# how can I completely remove an iOS app from the device as if it was never installed?

Tags: ios, swift, debugging, uninstallation

Interesting situation here. So my app is buggy and crashes for everyone who install the app for the first time. However, when they uninstall and reinstall the app, the bugs go away. Here's my challenge; because I already have installed the app on my device, I cannot replicate the crash. I already removed the iCould backup from the settings and it did not help. I somehow need to replicate the bug and the only way is to stage a scenario as if the app was never installed on my phone. Any help is appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: Are you using keychain by any chance?

Answer (score 1):

The best solution would be to restore the device to factory defaults - it will reset everything that could be potentially written on a device.

Otherwise it heavily depends on what kind of storage method you are using.
For files kept in `NSUserDefaults` it's just enough to delete the application from HomeView.

But if you use `KeyChain` as a storage for example, it won't be enough as data will not be removed together with the application.

If you have exact crash report maybe you can post it, so we can advice a bit more on direction to reproduce it.
It should be possible to easily reset simulator to Factory Defaults - that will be an easy way to test "fresh" installation.